# apache spark sql query optimization and saving result values?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large data in text files (1,000,000 lines) .Each line has 128 columns .
Here each line is a feature and each column is a dimension.

I have converted the txt files in json format and able to run sql queries on json file using spark.
Now i am trying to build a kd tree with this large data . 
My steps :
1) calculate variance of each column pick the column with maximum variance and make it as key first node , mean of the column as the value of the node.
2) based on the first node value split the data into 2 parts an repeat the process until you reach a point.

my sample code :

```
import sqlContext._
val people = sqlContext.jsonFile("siftoutput/")
people.printSchema()
people.registerTempTable("people")
val output = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * From people")
```

the people table has 128 columns

My questions :
1) How to save result values of a query into a list ?
2) How to calculate variance of a column ?
3) i will be runnig multiple queries on same data .Does spark has any way to optimize it ?
4) how to save the output as key value pairs in a text file ?

please help

Comment: That sample code is quite far from the described steps.

Comment: i just want to show how i am getting data from files and how i am running my queries .

Comment: btw, why convert csv data to json? It's just increasing size for no apparent added value.

Comment: Regarding the sample code, it does need to show some more effort from your side. 3 of the 4 questions are directly answered on the Spark documentation.